# Postgres pg_restore values only

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have two Postgres servers, which are (almost) mirrored copies of each other, with only differences being values in tables and owner names. Now, I want to overwrite values on server1 with those from server2, without changing owner names, schema and so on. Values in tables only. Is there any way to accomplish this with pg_dump and pg_restore?

Comment: Probably, you can link (dblink) both tables and make an update/insert/merge query.

Comment: You can do `pg_dump -d some-db -U  some-user -t the-table --data-only -f the_table.sql` which will result in a plain text file of only the table data. You would then need to `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` the data in the receiving table manually.  Then you could do `psql -d other-db -U some-use -f the_table.sql`.  Caveat is if the receiving table is the parent in  a foreign key relationship then you will not be able to delete the data without cascading that to the child table(s).